# I want to make a record of all the changes of my array - Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I want to make a dynamic array that stores a game board (chess) but the board is stored in a 2d array. how can I update an array by increasing the size without deleting the stored data?

```
String[][] TablaInicial = new String[17][17];
List<List<String>> Prueba = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
 for (i=0; i<17; i++) {
                for (y=0; y<17; y++) {
                    Prueba.get(i).get(y).add(TablaInicial[i][y]);
                }
            }
```

But I get this error: The method add(String) is undefined for the type String

Comment: `Prueba.get(i)` returns element `i` (assuming it exists), which would be a `List<String>`. `Preueba.get(i).get(y)` returns a `String`, which would be the element at `y` (assuming it exists) in that `List<String>`

Comment: Do you want to increase the size of `TablaInicial`, or do you want to know how to build `Prueba` from it?  As the code you provide isn't valid code, I'm not sure what you're trying to demonstrate with it.

Comment: I am making a game called quoridor, I need to make a log that saves all the movements of a player. The movement is stored in a 2d string Array so what I'm trying to do is to put it in a dynamic Array and increase the size to introduce another change in the array.

Comment: The O/P has not actually asked a question. It is not clear if the O/P is seeking help understanding the compiler error and how to fix it, or is seeking advice on how to log changes to the chess board.

Comment: a advice on how I could save a 2d array to a dynamic array to log the movements of a player

Comment: I'm not familiar with the game of quoridor. Without knowing more about what a move is, and the requirements the log satisfies, we can only speculate.

Comment: and how can I print `String [][] past = log.get(m)`? or how do I print the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a helper method, you could create a log of complete board positions:

```
 String [][] theBoard = new String [17][17]; 
 List<String[][]> history = new ArrayList <> ();
 ... 
 history.add (copyBoard(theBoard));
 ... 
 String [][] somePastBoard = history.get(m); 
 ...
```

The helper method creates a `new` copy of a board:

```
 public String [][] copyBoard (String [][] board) {
    // precondition: board must not be empty
    String [][] theCopy = new String [board.length][board[0].length];
    for (int row = 0; row < board.length; ++row)
        for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; ++ col)
            theCopy [row][col] = board [row][col];
    
    return theCopy; 
}
```

Edit:

One way to print a board is to use `Arrays.deepToString (somePastBoard)`. This will print out on one line, grouping like this:   `[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]]` for a 3 by 5.

If you want neater results, you could create your own print methods, using a pair of nested loops.

Edit:

To print the entire history, iterate through the log using a `for` loop:  (untested)

```
  public static void printHistory (List<String[][]> log) {
      for (String [][] board : log) {
         System.out.println ("\n-------");
         for (String [] line : board) {
           System.out.println ();
             for (String s : line) {
                System.out.print (s + " ");
             }
         }
      }
  }
```

Comment: `history.get(m)` (m) is it to be used in loop?

Comment: `m` is a variable that indicates which board in the history to get.  It is most likely an index variable of a loop, but isn't necessarily so.

Comment: to call the class to print would be just `class.printHistory()` on MAIN?

Comment: @Naheshiko  As shown, it is a static method. Calling would look something like this: `printHistory (history)`, if calling it from inside the class. Yes, if you would like, you could make it an instance method.  In that case, you would call it with something like `foo.printHistory();`, putting  the name of an instance variable in place of `foo`.

Comment: I managed to print it, thank you very much for everything!!!

Answer (score 1):

you cannot. Updating the array leads to changing the data in it. You may be able to create another 2D Array. But in the case of a chess game a list or arraylist would be more suitable.
I suggest saving every change as an array of the 2 indecies of your board and the change that was made. Since we will deal with a numbers, a number for the kind of piece that was moved and another for the move that was made.
This would allow you to keep a log.

Comment: can I save the 2d array (log) in an arraylist?

Comment: sure. I would advise you do so. So you are not limited by the size of the array. If this solves your problem, I would kindly ask you to give me a green checkmark. :)